# Pandas - Equal occurrences of unique type for a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a Pandas DF called “DF”. I would like to sample data from the population in such a way that, given a occurrence count, N = 100 and column = "Type", I would like to print a total of 100 rows from that column in such a way that the distribution of occurrences of each type is equal.

| SNo | Type | Difficulty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Single | 5 |
| 2 | Single | 15 |
| 3 | Single | 4 |
| 4 | Multiple | 2 |
| 5 | Multiple | 14 |
| 6 | None | 7 |
| 7 | None | 4323 |

For instance, If I specify N = 3, the output must be :

| SNo | Type | Difficulty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Single | 5 |
| 3 | Multiple | 4 |
| 6 | None | 7 |

If for the number N, the occurrences of certain types do not meet the minimum split, I can randomly increase another count.

I am wondering on how to approach this programmatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) (pandas ≥ 1.1) with N divided by the number of types.

*NB. This assumes the N is a multiple of the number of types if you want a strict equality.*

```
N = 3
N2 = N//df['Type'].nunique()

out = df.groupby('Type').sample(n=N2)
```

##### handling non multiple of the number of types

Use the same as above and complete to N with random rows excluding those already selected.

```
N = 5
N2, R = divmod(N, df['Type'].nunique())

out = df.groupby('Type').sample(n=N2)

out = pd.concat([out, df.drop(out.index).sample(n=R)])
```

As there is still a chance that you complete with items of the same group, if you really want to ensure sampling from different groups replace the last step with:

```
out = pd.concat([out, df.drop(out.index).groupby('Type').sample(n=1).sample(n=R)]
```

Example output:

```
   SNo      Type  Difficulty
4    5  Multiple          14
6    7      None        4323
2    3    Single           4
3    4  Multiple           2
5    6      None          14
```

Comment: Yes, this works. But, for N = 5, it would still print out 3 values. I was hoping if there was a way to ensure we get N values at all times (In this case, by randomly picking up 2 other values from any two distribution)

Comment: It's possible, let update

Comment: Can you provide your input as DataFrame constructor? (easier to copy on a phone)

Comment: Sure. `df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"Single",5],[2,"Single",15],[3,"Single",4],[4,"Multiple",2],[5,"Multiple",14],[6,"None",14],[7,"None",4323]], columns=['SNo', 'Type', 'Difficulty'])`

Comment: Great, see update

Comment: I just added a small improvement